# SqlDependency.Start(connectionString) return every time false

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I set All right to acces the DataBase

```
use DbName
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO dbuser
use DbName
GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::schema.tableName TO dbuser
Use DbName
GRANT RECEIVE ON QueryNotificationErrorsQueue TO dbuser
ALTER DATABASE DbName SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
use DbName
alter database DbName SET ENABLE_BROKER
```

but when I start **SqlDependency**:

```
bool started = SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
```

//started is false and then I get this error

**An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance.**

C# code:

```
private static bool notificationEnabled = false;
private string connString= "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;UID=dbuser; PWD=pass;";
    public static void EnableNotifications()
    {
        // prevent for calling twice 
        if (notificationEnabled)return; 

        System.Web.Caching.SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableNotifications(connString);
        //startResult is false always
        bool startResult = SqlDependency.Start(connString);
        notificationEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Please show other code around that call. Also any other calls that may use the same connection string.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I added my code in c#

Comment: Does the problem go away if you swap the order of the calls of `SqlDependency.Start` and `SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableNotifications`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the queue name to your Start:

```
bool startResult = SqlDependency.Start(connString, queueName)
```

I also had to add the service name and timeout to my SqlDependency constructor to get things to work right. (its in VB, but you get the idea)

```
dependency = New SqlDependency(command, "Service=" + SERVICE_NAME + ";", Int32.MaxValue)
```